# How to organize names in a array by last name in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm having trouble trying to organize names in an array by last names. I can do it by the first name. If anyone could help that would be great.

This is organized by the first name.
I need help on how to organize by the last name.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names =
        {
            "Gary Sipowitz", "Baldwin Jones", "Greg Medavoy", "John Irvin", "Rita Ortiz",
            "Thomas Bale", "Laura Murphy", "Al Angelotti", "Robert Heilbrenner", "Joe Slovak",
            "Ray Quinn", "Basil Greenhouse", "Dale St John", "Felicia Heilbrenner", "Akira Nikada"
        };
        
        var result = from name in names
        
        orderby name
        select name;

        // Evaluate our query.
        foreach (string value in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Organized by Lastname:");
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just change to `orderby name.Split(' ').Last()` (add `using System.Linq;`)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the .Last() method until now. Thanks @OguzOzgul

Comment: Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have, plaese:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] names =
        {
            "Gary Sipowitz", "Baldwin Jones", "Greg Medavoy", "John Irvin", "Rita Ortiz",
            "Thomas Bale", "Laura Murphy", "Al Angelotti", "Robert Heilbrenner", "Joe Slovak",
            "Ray Quinn", "Basil Greenhouse", "Dale St John", "Felicia Heilbrenner", "Akira Nikada"
        };

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
        foreach (var item in names)
        {
            dict.Add(item, item.Split(' '));
        }

        var ordered = dict.OrderBy(e => e.Value[1]);

        Console.WriteLine("Organized by Lastname:");
        foreach (var element in ordered)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element.Key);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```